# Is storing object instances in file in Java a good idea?

Tags: java, object, serialization

I have a project where I would like to create minimal instances of a class across the whole project (in Java). Is it a good idea to serialize and deserialize the object and store it in a file? I will be using the class heavily across the whole project so I am not sure if that is a good solution. 
Are there any other methods to achieve this?

P.S. - I have this class as a singleton class

Comment: Well... If you can create more than a single instance it's **not** a Singleton.

Comment: A "singleton" class is not singleton across requests.

Comment: Are you redefining what Singleton is?

Comment: You can use a bean and inject it into the places you'll be needing this instance.

Comment: if it's a singleton, then you are subverting its singletonness when you deserialize it all over the place. not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @NathanHughes - I am trying to get one instance across all the different processes running in the project. This is easy to achieve when the project is a web application. I am not sure how to exactly do this when it is not.

Comment: @d_void what is your definition of "project". Your last comment seems to imply that there are multiple "processes" in your "project". And, you want a single instance of your class-instance across all processes, is that right?

Comment: @StvnBrkdll - yes exactly. Sorry for the ambiguous question.

Comment: What is the data that your "class" manages? Typical ways to manage shared state across processes would be to store the state in a shared database, or use something like a distribute cache or a distributed key-value store (ehcache, redis, etc).

Comment: @StvnBrkdll - It basically just logs information depending upon different parameters provided

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a good idea and it should be self-explanatory why.
If you want to get into detail as to why you shouldn't use the approach you suggested, then have a look at *@Joachim Sauer*'s answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191269/java-serialization-advantages-and-disadvantages-use-or-avoid).

Without knowing what you intend to do with the class you want to re-use, it sounds like you need something like a static instance.

So, instead of confusing yourself with what the singleton design pattern is, just create an instance of that class, in (preferably) your main class like this:

```
public static ClassIWantToStore reusable = new ClassIWantToStore();
```

Or if you want a different instance of the class each time:

```
//THIS IS NOT SINGLETON
public static ClassIWantToStore getNewInstance(){
  //Modify functionality if you want something more 
  //before returning the class instance.
  return new ClassIWantToStore();
}
```

*I recommend you read what the static keyword does in Java, which could prove useful to situations like the one you're in now; but it should also be used carefully, because it can help you shoot yourself in the leg when misused. 
[This](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-is-the-static-keyword-in-java/) is a good and simple explanation of the **static** keyword.*